# Não consigo mostrar dados do banco com ajax,php e jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, banco-de-dados

Eu preciso que ao clicar no *checkbox*, ele faça uma consulta no banco de dados e me retorne dentro de uma div. Porém consigo puxar os dados com ajax e mostrar na div diretamente(home_.php está mostrando o select que fiz), mas ao juntar o evento de clicar com ajax, não consigo obter nada.

-Ao clicar no checkbox, ele vai consultar o BD,e me mostrar o resultado na div, vão ser flexbox.

**HTML**

```
<div id="conteudo">
                RESULTADO:
            </div>
<div class="checkboxes">

                        <input type="checkbox" id="regua">
                        <label for="regua">Régua</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="motor">
                        <label for="motor">Motor</label> <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="canal">
                        <label for="canal">Canal</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="fase">
                        <label for="fases">Fase</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="vigencia">
                        <label for="vigencia">Vigência</label>

                    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 $("#regua").click(function(){
                         if($('#regua').is(':checked')){

                           }
                     });

            </script>
```

**AJAX**

```
            <script>
                       $.ajax({
                                url: "home_.php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
                                success: function (data) {                                  
                                    $('#conteudo').html(data); 
                                    $('#conteudo').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

                                },
                                error: function (request, status, erro) {

                                    $('#conteudo').html('Ocorreu um erro, entre em contato com T.I!', erro);
                                    $('#conteudo').show();
                                }
                            });
            </script>
```

**home_.php**

```
<?php
include_once("./php/conect_postgre.php");

  $consulta_bd = "SELECT * FROM uniao  WHERE regua LIKE 'Co%'";

  $result=pg_query($conexao, $consulta_bd);
  if  (($result)){
      while($linha_usuario = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo $linha_usuario['regua'] . "<br>";
      }
  }else{
      echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
  }
```

Comment: Vc tem que colocar o AJAX dentro de `if($('#regua').is(':checked')){`. Outra coisa, o script `$("#regua").click(function(){` tem que vir no final do `body`.

Comment: Alterei como disse, e mesmo clicando, não me retorna os dados, quando ajax ta sozinho puxando, traz normalmente.

Comment: Colocou o script no final do `body`?

Comment: sim coloquei, seria antes do </body> né?

Comment: Isso. Coloque um `alert("ok");` dentro do if pra ver se está chamando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                 $("#regua").click(function(){
                         if($('#regua').is(':checked')){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "home_.php",  // coloque aqui o endereço que vai buscar os dados no banco         
                                success: function (data) {                                  
                                    $('#conteudo').html(data); 
                                    $('#conteudo').show(); // Mostrar o retorno em texto no html

                                      $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                                        $('#conteudo').html(element.regua); // não sei como ta o teu retorno
                                        $('#conteudo').html(element.linha_usuario); // ou assim
                                     });

                                },
                                error: function (request, status, erro) {

                                    $('#conteudo').html('Ocorreu um erro, entre em contato com T.I!', erro);
                                    $('#conteudo').show();
                                }
                            });
                           }
                     });

            </script>
```

Comment: MEU DEUS!!! VOCÊ É 10 MOÇA!!! TE VENERO!!! FUNCIONOOOOOOOOOOOOOOU

Comment: Por nada... A intenção é essa..